# Lubuntu Panel Applet or Indicator to display Mounted Volumes

Tags: mount, lubuntu, pcmanfm

I'm a satisfied Lubuntu user but I cannot find an applet or indicator that
displays the mounted volumes (and eventually allows to unmount them).

So far the only way to know what is currently mounted is from the terminal (command mount) or open the file manager (pcmanfm).

If anybody knows a package I can install for the purpose (panel applet or indicator) please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried Nautilus?

Comment: Nautilus is incredible slow when there are many files on the disk, even if I disable all the previews and do everything possible to make it faster. Nautilus 3.x is in my opinion absolutely unusable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered this nice indicator:

```
sudo apt-get install ejecter
```

after installed you click Alt+F2 and enter

```
ejecter
```

to run it.

To have it start automatically at login create a file named ejecter.desktop in ~/.config/autostart:

```
nano ~/.config/autostart/ejecter.desktop
```

with the following content

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Ejecter
Exec=ejecter
Terminal=false
Type=Application
NoDisplay=true
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of file managers that you can use with Ubuntu.

[Here is a site](http://www.tuxarena.com/2011/06/20-file-managers-for-ubuntu/)  that lists 20 of them and how to install them.

Comment: I tried plenty of file managers but so far the best one I found is pcmanfm even if quite buggy. In this context I'm more searching for an applet/indicator, then I hope pcmanfm will get improved.